# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have jsp code where i am getting error at line 6.

```
 <%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
 <html>
 <body>
 <center>
    <h3>Enter your Login Details</h3>
    <html:form action="/loginaction">
 Enter user ID:<html:text property="uname" />
        <br>
 Enter Password:<html:password property="pwd" />
        <br>
        <html:submit />
        <html:reset />
    </html:form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I have written java classes in default package in eclipse.
And .classes are not generated.
what is the problem help me.....

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/webroot_struts] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException:
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class j.LoginActionForm under form name x] with root cause
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class j.LoginActionForm under form name x
at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.initFormBean(FormTag.java:536)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:503)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f0(login_jsp.java:117)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:89)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: You have not provided the **full stacktrace**. How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: Without your action configuration and more details it's impossible to help.